# Help modifying window opening. American Concrete Institute standards? Building code?

Tags: code-compliance, masonry, building-regulations, concrete-block, florida

I'm remodeling my kitchen and part of the work that I want to do involves modifying my window rough openings. Currently, the windows in my kitchen are lower than the countertop backsplash and I want to raise them up above the counter so that they're easy to open and don't collect dust and trash, etc.

My house was built in 1968 and it's constructed of single-wythe CMU walls with no stucco. I'm located in Florida and this construction is very common for older homes in Florida. My plan for this work is as follows:

1. Remove the current wood sills. Lucky me, these should come right out.
2. Mortar an additional row of block into the bottom of the window openings.
3. Secure the new block to the wall by drilling rebar into the sides and through the bottoms of the existing block.
4. Fill the CMU webs with grout.
5. Mortar a new precast sill on top of the new row of block.
6. Install new windows.

I'm doing this work on an owner/builder permit. I submitted this week to add this window/masonry work to my existing permit and my city's building department has come back to me asking for additional information before they'll approve. They've asked me to show compliance with Florida Building Code and the American Concrete Institute for the alteration to the window opening that I've proposed. I'm generally familiar with the Florida Building Code but I am stumped by one requirement – more on this later.

It's the question about showing compliance with the American Concrete Institute that really has me concerned. This is a lot of information to read, and I bet that the parts that I need to be concerned with comprise only a very small part of their total body of standards.

My first question is, is anyone familiar with the American Concrete Institute's standards or requirements, or best practices, etc. and can you point me to the general direction of what I should read to learn enough to ensure that my alteration will be compliant?

My second question has to do with the Florida Build Code 6th edition section R703.4 "Flashing." Specifically the requirement that "Approved corrosion resistant flashings shall be installed at the following locations... #3 Under and at the ends of masonry, wood or metal copings and sills." Does this require that I install flashing under (and to the sides of) the precast concrete sill? If this is required, how should I attach the sill to the block? I would expect the use of a sill pan, for example, would prevent adequate surface for mortaring the precast sill to the block. If I can't mortar the sill to the block, what will hold it in place?

I will be flashing the window according to the window manufacturer's instructions (Pella), but these of course don't say anything about the window rough opening or sill construction.

The included drawing should hopefully convey the work that I'm doing. Any help at all as appreciated.

[image: window alteration drawings]

Comment: You should get installation instructions from the manufacturer of the precast sill. If a flashing is required it should be addressed in those specs. and the specs. will likely include compliance references to industry standards. Install the sill "as directed by the manufacturer" and the AHJ is likely to accept that in lieu of conformance to the other.

Comment: It's likely that your AHJ will tell you what they want if you ask nicely. May be easier than making guesses and having them say "Nope, not it."

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I emailed my city's building department to ask about the sill specifically. I did ask nicely, so fingers crossed. Regarding installation instructions for the sill, that's great advice, but my local shop that builds these doesn't provide instructions. They make sills, benches, birdbaths, etc. and I think they figure you just know how to do the work already.

Comment: Might not hurt to ask the local shop for instruction. "Hey, I'm a rookie, got any pointers that'll make sure the building dept will be happy with my install?"

Comment: Wow that seams crazy as that is not a structural change, just making the window shorter from the bottom I would not have needed a permit. But we don’t have hurricanes either just earthquakes LOL

Comment: @Ed Beal, it sounds like OP is doing an extensive remodel and pulled permit as Owner-Builder. Inspector now has free reign to look at everything new (and in my area, they can make you bring other stuff not in-scope up to current depending on how extensive the remodel...)

Comment: @JimmyFix-it exactly. I'm remodeling the entire kitchen and these windows are right near where I'll be doing a bunch of plumbing and electrical work and I thought I better tell them about this rather than try to do it sneakily.

Comment: I'd get a sheet metal guy to fab a sill with back dam and side dams.  I'd sit the concrete sill on the sheet metal sill and PL it.  You could also use a metal L and secure the sill to the side blocks before you sit your window on it.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger is that a typical installation?

Comment: Probably overkill that is more a door rough opening detail. It depends on the window details but you want to water proof your rough opening and then install your window.  In wood construction you typically use something like blue skin or flex wrap on the rough opening.  You could do that too, flexwrap might be rough enough to take mortar.